# Liferay does not display UTF8 characters anymore

Tags: mysql, linux, liferay, mysql-workbench

I just made a database restore from mysql workbench and found out that liferay does not display UTF-8 spec characters e.g ÅÄÖ, these letters are instead displayed as a question mark.
I wonder if anyone knows the solution for this issue? Do I have to specify a charset while importing the sql files? And if so how do I do that in mysql workbench?

To be honest I have no idea if the mysql restore has a direct effect on what happened, I'm just describing what I did before the issue occurred.

Comment: In which charset is your file, from which you are doing restore?

Comment: I checked with file -I filename (in the terminal) and it said us-ascii, should this really have an affect when it's clearly specified in the text from the sql files to use utf8? If so do you know any good convertor for mac? There are quite a lot of files that would have to be converted in that case.

Comment: Can you open your file in text editor of your choice and see whether your "special" characters are there or question marks?

Comment: The special characters are there

Comment: can you try converting with "iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 < file.old > file.new"

Comment: I Have already tried that and the charset stays us-ascii. Although i just resaved everything manually and are going to se if it works as soon as I got the possibility.

Comment: Ok. Just on question, are you doing dump from command line or making export from workbench?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a restore to a new database, make sure that this database defaults the character set to UTF-8:

```
create database lportal character set utf8;
```

Then import your data into that table.

Let me also use this opportunity to link my favourite site to generate great UTF-8 testdata: http://www.fliptitle.com - great if you need testdata for people who know only ASCII languages but still need immediate feedback on correct encoding with data they're able to interpret. You don't seem to be one of them, but I guess others that are in this group might stumble upon this later.